# Flutter, difficulty achieving bottom navigation bar design

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to achieve this type of bottom navigation bar for an app, but I have no idea on how to achieve those animations without causing errors. Please help.

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f4/f0/7a/f4f07aa287a3fcbc881051ce7bc74c6e.gif

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [persistent_bottom_nav](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) package from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev)